# What to do with kiddush cups that are too small?

Tags: shiurim-measurements, kiddush-cup

If one comes to own a kiddush cup that is well under a reviis, is there a way the cup can be used for a mitzvah and not be left in a closet forever? What can be done with a kiddush cup that is too small? Because it was intended for a mitzvah I'd rather use it for a mitzvah if there is such an option. The cup in question has a capacity of 50ml, which is less than 2 fl. oz. and certainly much less that the minimum shiur for kiddush according to all shitot I know.

Comment: You can use it as a Kebeitza measuring cup.

Comment: It's pretty close to 50cc. As close as my measuring cup will take me, it's about 55cc.
So yeah! That's an entertaining idea!

Comment: Could it have come from a [kiddush fountain set](http://www.israel-catalog.com/sites/default/files/products/images/sterling-silver-kiddush-wine-fountain-12-cups-floral-diamond-pattern.jpg), maybe?

Comment: Monica: No. It's not from a set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to msh210's ideas, these would be appropriate esp. if the cup is silver (or gold!):

- Leaving inheritance for your kids is a mitzvah. So let the cup sit around for them.
- You can either sell it and donate the money to a tzedaka or donate the cup itself to an org. (Hey! How about "Yiddishe Cups"?)

Comment: For "donating the cup", should we be choshesh for lifnei iver?

Comment: @DanielMoskovich If that's your concern, there's an easy solution. Explain things when you donate it.

Comment: Is leaving a bigger inheritance for your kids a bigger mitzvah? I don't know why that would be the case.

Comment: @DoubleAA Not sure what you mean by "bigger" or where you see that I either said or even implied that.

Comment: @DanF As long as he already owns 1 dollar to give as inheritance he's fulfilling that Mitzva, so why is keeping this cup a Mitzva?

Answer (score 6):

> Because it was intended for a mitzvah I'd rather use it for a mitzvah if there is such an option.

I've never heard of such a thing, as far as I recall. I've heard that it's nice to [reuse something for a *mitzva*](/q/22701) if it **was used** for a *mitzva*, but not if it was merely intended for such use.

But no matter: that's what you want, that's what I'll address.

Here are some things you can do with a small cup (some of which are merely nice things to do rather than true *mitzvos*):

- Use it to [partake of someone's *kos shel b'racha*](/a/11228).
- Rework it into something else that can be used for a *mitzva* purpose. (E.g., if it's metal, make it an *izmel*.)
- Use it as [a *sudar*](/a/215) or as *shave kesef* for various *kinyanim* that are *mitzvos* (e.g. *kidushin*).
- Stuff it, bottom first, into your mouth when you find yourself about to say *lashon hara*.
- [Give it as a prize for *Chanuka*.](/a/3577)

Comment: cup for Mayim Ahronim? These are rather small

Comment: @mbloch, by all means post an answer.

Comment: I was offering it as a possible addition to your answer - it wouldn't deserve one of its own

Comment: @mbloch Many would think 50cc is too small for that